# Yii urlManager language in URL

Tags: php, url-routing, yii

I am trying to add a language to the url with following syntax:
    http://www.example.com/en/site/page/view/about

What I have so far works with short urls like:
    http://www.example.com/en/site/contact
but not with long once as in my first example

Here is what I have so far:

/config/main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'class'=>'application.components.MyCUrlManager',
    'urlFormat'=>'path', 'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        '<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

---

```
<?php // components/MyCUrlManager.php

class MyCUrlManager extends CUrlManager
{
    public function createUrl($route,$params=array(),$ampersand='&')
    {
        if(isset($_POST['_lang']))
        {
            Yii::app()->setLanguage($_POST['_lang']);
            $route['language']=Yii::app()->language;
        }
        elseif (!isset($route['language']))
        {
            $route['language']=Yii::app()->language;
        }
        else
        {
            Yii::app()->setLanguage($route['language']);
        }
        return parent::createUrl($route, $params, $ampersand);
    }
}
?>
```

---

```
class LangBox extends CWidget {

    public function run() {

        $currentLang = Yii::app()->language;
        require_once 'Zend/Locale.php';
        $locale = new Zend_Locale();
        //$siteLanguages = $this->getLang();
        $siteLanguages = array('en','de','tr');
        foreach($siteLanguages as $value){
                $list[$value] = $locale->getTranslation($value, 'Language', $value);
        }
        asort($list);
        $this->render('langBox', array('currentLang' => $currentLang, 'list'=>$list));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you expect `http://www.example.com/en/site/page/view/about` to go? Which controller, action etc?

Comment: Static Page: 
    site = controller, 
    page = static page, 
    view = directory, 
    page = about  => abaut.php,  


Non Static Page: ,
    en = language, 
    segment2 = controller, 
    segment3 = action,

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem, and following rules work for me also with submodules and any number of params:

```
                 '<lang:[a-z]{2}>/<_m>/<_c>' => '<_m>/<_c>',
                 '<lang:[a-z]{2}>/<_m>/<_c>/<_a>*' => '<_m>/<_c>/<_a>',
                 '<lang:[a-z]{2}>/<_m>/<_a>' => '<_m>/<_a>',
                 '<lang:[a-z]{2}>/<_c>' => '<_c>',
                 '<lang:[a-z]{2}>/<_c>/<_a>' => '<_c>/<_a>',
```

_m is special value for module, _c for controller and _a for action.