# Yii URL rewrite and add another language

Tags: url-rewriting, yii, lang

I am using yii and my site structure like this:

the main folder is "ar"

```
ar
├───assets
├───css
├───images
├───protected
└───themes
```

and the posts links be like the :

www.example.com/**ar**/post/view/id/499

when i build the site there was no need to build the site with multi language support, so i made a mistake and create the app in the folder "ar" which the short for "arabic" :(.

Now i need to add english language to the site and i don't want the url be like this:

www.example.com/**ar/en**/post/view/id/499

and i don't want to rename main folder "ar" because i don't want to lose current site post links.

So, What do you advise me to solve my problem? and what are the best way to think when we make multi language site?

can i use .htaccess file or Yii URL Manager to do rewrite for the url when the langauge is **english** and he found the url like this: www.example.com/**ar/en**/post/view/id/499 Converts it to be like this: www.example.com/**en**/post/view/id/499

Thank You in Advance

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/294/seo-conform-multilingual-urls-language-selector-widget-i18n/

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to change urls. Simply move content of ar to parent directory, and fix paths where applicable. When you move folders, leave folder `ar` empty and add `en` folder. In each folder place .htaccess with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* ../index.php
```

Your folders layout should look like:

```
ar
en
... possibly more languages
assets
css
images
protected
themes
```

Advantage with this config is that you don't need htaccess in main web folder `/`

For rewrite rules for such layout i answered in other question:

[Yii urlManager language in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574181/yii-urlmanager-language-in-url/4625710#4625710)