# Passing language as variable as url parameter in yii

Tags: php, internationalization, yii

i'm having a problem with yii which seems very simple but i can't find an appropriate solution for it. I need to do I18N in web page and i'm using yii, i have translations already done, i found that it's possible to easily change language in controller class like that:

```
class Controller extends CController
{
    function init() {
        parent::init();
        if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
            Yii::app()->language = 'lt';
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is ok, but obviously the language parameter is lost when url doesn't contain the language parameter. One way around is adding the parameter in all urls across whole site, but that doesn't seem like a solution.

Is there some more static way of passing the parameter? Maybe some option in UrlManager in yii? Or maybe there is another way of changing the language more dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution is to use session data to remember the user's language choice across pages:

```
function init() {
    parent::init();
    $app = Yii::app();

    // If "lang" is specified, remember that
    if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
        $app->session['language'] = 'lt';
    }

    // If we remember a language put it in use
    if($app->session->contains('language')) {
        $app->language = $app->session['language'];
    }

}
```

Comment: While it is simple it is bad solution, it makes that different content will be available on same urls.

Comment: @PeterM: And that is bad because...? If your app is not public and being indexed I don't see any problem, and I don't consider these properties as given for any random code we are discussing.

Comment: Yup this helps me, since my app is not public, logged in users will see their selected language, thanks :)

Comment: @Jon well, i guess i was thinking about not only multilanguage interface, but also multilanguage data. With multilingual data it is impossible, for example to send link to other user etc.

Answer (score 1):

And what if you'll use session only when get-request is absent? 
But it is still bad idea to show different content on the same url.

```
    if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
          $app->session['language'] = 'lt';
    } elseif($app->session->contains('language')) {
          $app->language = $app->session['language'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easy add it as static param to url manager rules. I recommend using urls in form `/en/controller/action` etc, so first parameter is always language. I'm using this approach for long time and works like a charm.

For details check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4625710/133408